# Joining and group_concat with three tables

Tags: mysql

**Table details:**

```
 CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `user` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO `table1` (`user`, `id`) VALUES ('bob', '1');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`user`, `id`) VALUES ('bob', '2');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`user`, `id`) VALUES ('kev', '3');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`user`, `id`) VALUES ('kev', '4');

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `data1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `data2` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES ('1', 'a', 'a1');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES ('1', 'b', 'b1');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES ('1', 'b', 'c1');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES ('2', 'a', 'd1');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES ('2', 'b', 'e1');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES ('3', 'g', 'f1');

CREATE TABLE `table3` (
    `id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `data11` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `data22` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO `table3` (`id`, `data11`, `data22`) VALUES ('1', 'a10', 'a11');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`id`, `data11`, `data22`) VALUES ('1', 'b10', 'b11');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`id`, `data11`, `data22`) VALUES ('1', 'c10', 'c11');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`id`, `data11`, `data22`) VALUES ('2', 'd10', 'd11');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`id`, `data11`, `data22`) VALUES ('2', 'e10', 'e11');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`id`, `data11`, `data22`) VALUES ('3', 'f10', 'f11');
```

**My Tried query is:**

```
   select 
            t1.user,
            t1.id,
            group_concat(t2.data1 ) d1,
            group_concat( t2.data2) d2,
            group_concat( t3.data11 ) d11,
            group_concat(t3.data22 ) d22
        from table1 t1
        left join table2 t2 
                on   t2.id = t1.id
        left join table3 t3
                on t3.id = t1.id
                where t1.user='bob' group by t1.id;
```

but i get multiple datas in d1,d2,d11,d22 and because of second left join

**Expected Output:**

```
+-------+------+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  user |   id |     d1     |     d2    |       d11     |     d22       |
+-------+------+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  bob  |   1  |   a,b,b    | a1,b1,c1  |  a10,b10,c10  |  a11,b11,c11  |
|  bob  |   2  |   a,b      | d1,e1     |  d10,e10      |  d11,e11      |
+-------+------+------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Actually i'm storing array data from api to mysql using jdbc i inserted data in three tables now i have to retrive these data and form a array format and send it to web api, so does anyone here know how to do this? Do I need to do a nested query?

Comment: Please add the effort you have done to accomplish what you want, share your source code.

Comment: thanks @agtabesh I'm making more progress on asking proper question format is that clear

Comment: See GROUP_CONCAT - although I would handle this kind of thing in application code.

Comment: As above, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.user,
       t1.id,
       t2.d1,
       t2.d2,
       t3.d11,
       t3.d22
       FROM table1 t1
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.id,
                              group_concat(t2.data1) d1,
                              group_concat(t2.data2) d2
                              FROM table2 t2
                              GROUP BY t2.id) t2
                      ON t2.id = t1.id
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT t3.id,
                              group_concat(t3.data11) d11,
                              group_concat(t3.data22) d22
                              FROM table3 t3
                             GROUP BY t3.id) t3
                      ON t3.id = t1.id
      WHERE t1.user = 'bob';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id
     , GROUP_CONCAT(t2.data ORDER BY t2.data) x
  FROM Table1 t1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Table2 t2 
    ON t2.id = t1.id 
 GROUP 
    BY t1.id;
+----+----------+
| id | x        | 
+----+----------+
| 15 | A1,B1,C1 |
| 16 | H        |
| 17 | NULL     |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: thanks  Strawberry actually it works with two table just found if i add another left as shown in my application code the x table value a1,b1,c1,a1,b1,c1 returning two times like that i wil upload the error in new.

Comment: Cool - remember that as contributors begin to notice your voting record, they may be disinclined to help in future.